# Match SUM or concatenation of multiple elements of same JSON array using Karate

Tags: arrays, json, testing, automation, karate

Having a JSON Response with so many musical instruments in multiple sets (>100+). How to Best match each of the item set `item_list` value with exact Sum or concatenation of `item_number` and `item_info`.

> Validation failing at below Sum or concatenation:

> `* match each response[*].item_list = $response[*].item_number + "--" + $response[*].item_info`

```
[{
   "item_number":01,
   "item_info": "Piano",
   "item_list": "01--Piano"
 },
 {
   "item_number":02,
   "item_info": "Mrudanga",
   "item_list": "02--Mrudanga"
 },
 {
   "item_number":03,
   "item_info": "Guitar",
   "item_list": "03--Guitar"
 },
 {
   "item_number":04,
   "item_info": "Flute",
   "item_list": "04--Flute"
 },
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This would work](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#referring-to-self) if the number values were proper:

```
* match each response contains { item_list: "#(_$.item_number + '--' + _$.item_info)" }
```

You may need to do some pre-processing:

```
* def data = response.map(x => String(x.item_number).padStart(2, '0') + '--' + x.item_info)
* match response[*].item_list == data
```